# Brute force attack on vsftp server not showing failed authentication in log

Tags: debian, security, vsftpd, fail2ban

My server is running Debian 8 with vsftpd version 3.0.2-17. Recently my vsftpd.log filled up with the following:

**vsftpd.log**

```
Mon Mar  7 18:13:44 2016 [pid 13499] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
Mon Mar  7 18:13:45 2016 [pid 13501] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
Mon Mar  7 18:13:46 2016 [pid 13503] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
Mon Mar  7 18:13:47 2016 [pid 13505] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
...
...
```

This goes on for over 6000 lines, all from the same IP address (I obfuscated the IP in the log file snippet). I have a fail2ban (version 0.8.13-1) jail running using the default vsftpd.conf file, but there are no authentication failures being logged, so no ban. Here is the filter for reference:

**fail2ban vsftpd.conf regex**

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(__pam_re)s\s+authentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* t$
        ^ \[pid \d+\] \[.+\] FAIL LOGIN: Client "<HOST>"\s*$
```

And here is my vsftpd configuration file:

**vsftpd.conf**

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=<path to .pem file>
rsa_private_key_file=<path to key file>
ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_min_port=XXXX
pasv_max_port=XXXX
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on? Why are there no failed login attempts in the log? I can't find any other evidence that someone actually gained access to the system.

BTW, my intentions were to start and stop the vsftpd service only when I needed to use it myself, but I failed to remove it from startup, so when I re-booted it was started again without me realizing it. I have since corrected that problem, but I would still like to understand this issue, and how I could get fail2ban work with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect operation and login operation are not the same stuff.

Some bots in the internet can just check if your FTP server is alive and disconnect without even trying to login (sometimes in the loop like in your case). That's normal. There is no issue here.

You can try it on your own. Simply execute:

```
$ telnet whatever-domain.com 21
Trying 999.9.9.9...
Connected to whatever-domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

and check `vsftpd log`, there should appear only line where you are trying to `CONNECT` and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. OK, so they are not trying to login. That makes sense. But they are still making my log file huge by doing this. Is there a way to configure fail2ban for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I played around a bit with your input and `fail2ban-regex` and was able to match those lines with this `failregex`:

`failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s\s*\[pid\s*\d*\]:\s*CONNECT:\s*Client\s*\"<HOST>\"`

I'm sure you could further refine that, but the key point is that the default `__prefix_line` is confused by having `[pid 13499]` instead of just `[13499]`, so you have to either locally modify the prefix or else include the pid part in the body of the regex.

As long as you don't set too low a threshold, this should give you the behavior you're looking for: blocking anyone who makes repeated connections in a short period of time.

Comment: This failregex didn't work for me. But this one did: `^ \[pid \d+\] CONNECT: Client "<HOST>"(?:\s*$|,)`